# Bound for eigenvalues of some special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $Tridiagonal(a, c, b)= \begin{vmatrix}
c & b & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
a &  c & b & \ldots & 0 \\
0 &  a & c & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
0 &  0 &  0 &  a &  c
\end{vmatrix}$

and consider $A=Tridiagonal(1, -2, 1), B=Tridiagonal(-1, 0, 1), M=A^{-1}B$

Is there known any bound for the maximum of the eigenvalues of $M$?

The bound $\rho(M)\leq || A^{-1} || \cdot || B || $ is too crude.

Comment: in fact all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix  are known. i don't have the formula handy but you can see in the textbook on numerical algebra by todd. i remember it depends only on the product $ab.$

Comment: Thanks so much abel. Are you sure? I know the eigenvalues of A and B separately (and $A^{-1}$ and $B$), but... are known the eigenvalues of the product of $A^{-1}B$? I'm not so sure they're known

Answer (score 1):

**A slightly longer comment:**

By examining the structure of a few $M:=A^{-1}B$ for various $n$, it seems to me that the rows of $M$ satisfy
$$\tag{1}
m_{ii}+m_{ij}=\begin{cases}-1&\text{for $j>i$,}\\+1&\text{for $j<i$,}\end{cases}
\quad
|m_{ii}|\leq 1, \quad i=1,\ldots,n,
$$
that is, the diagonal entries are between $-1$ and $1$, the off-diagonal entries in the same row are constant to left and to right from the diagonal entry and have a special relation w.r.t. the diagonal entry.

Assuming this can be somehow shown (probably by premultiplying this assumed form of $M$ by $A$ and comparing it to $B$) then
$$
\rho(M)\leq\|M\|_{\infty}\leq 1 + 2(n-1).
$$
For example, for $n=1000$, this gives
$$
\rho(M)\approx 318.6,
\quad
\|M\|_\infty=999,
\quad
1+2(n-1)=1999,
\quad
\|A^{-1}\|_2\|B\|_2\approx 2.0\cdot 10^5,
$$
so the estimate does not look so bad (overestimates the real spectral radius by less than an order of magnitude) and is not far from the real $\infty$-norm (by about a factor of 2). Of course, one would need to show (1).

Comment: It's very useful, and I like your technique about try to "guess" the form of M. Maybe I would work by this way and obtain something interesting. However, I must apologize with the forum, because I put a simply form of my real problem. In my real problem, $A=tridiagonal(\alpha, 1+2\alpha, \alpha)$, $B=tridiagonal(-\beta, 0, \beta)$, and I would like to prove that $\rho(M)<1$... and even $||M||_{\infty}$ is too crude... so, your bound it's not valid for my purpose. But, again, thank you very much, and the problem is still open.

Comment: @user14545 I see. Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ somehow related? Do you mean $B=\mathrm{tridiag}(-\beta,0,\beta)$ instead of $B=\mathrm{tridiag}(\beta,0,\beta)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry again, I just correct. In esence, $\alpha\approx 1/n^2$, $\beta\approx 1/4n^2$ (both multiply by a factor, that seems not have importance). Of course, I have computed the eigenvalues for small $n$ in matlab, and the eigenvalues are bounded by 1.